# What are the problems with existence of an "Omniscience Machine" within the constraints of collective human knowledge?

Tags: dataset, natural-language, philosophical

"If a machine can read and *process written texts, manuscripts, journal articles and books*, it would be able to predict results of new scientific experiments and construct new scientific theories."

What are the main problems with the above statement? I can think of the following categories, but I believe the list is more extensive. This question is asking for references and terminology to refer to each limitation not opinions.

- Natural language processing limitations.
- Computational resource limitations.
- Human resources limitations.
- Problems within philosophy of science which pertains to all predictions and scientific theories in general.
- Inherent deficiencies of any programmable machine that limits its ability to construct new scientific theories.

---

After reading the answer and comments:

- Limitations of the corpus.

Answer (score 3):

Very wrong. It assumes that the existing corpus of written texts contains virtually all information about the past, present, and future of the universe, and so all that is required is clever processing of existing data. In other words, the claim is that humanity has collected all the data it will ever need and just has to sit down and think about it for a while (or build Deep Thought to do that). I don't see how that could possibly be a justified claim.

Comment: Plus all the ridiculous nonsense that gets published regularly. I suppose a good machine learning algorithm might already be able to learn to recognize fraudulent or poor quality publications to some extent. E.g. for the former categories it might learn that hints are images that are mirrored ones from other papers, implausibly low variability, blatant number preferences... For the second category stepwise regression or multiple comparisons without adjustments etc. But some things are less obvious or require good expectations on what is plausible.